# Clicking next or previous makes the page scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

At first kindly visit this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XvAR6/

Now scroll down to see.

Here I have used jQuery ui. But, that is not the problem, the main problem is when I click next or previous the page automatically scrolls to top. I don't want the scrolling. Can I get a solution for it?

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$("#tab1, #tab2").tabs({active: 1});

var all = $('.udtalelse').addClass("passiv");

var i = -1;

$('#prev').click(function() {
    ctrlKunder( i = !i ? all.length - 1 : --i );
});
$('#next').click(function() {
    ctrlKunder( i = ++i % all.length );
}).click();

function ctrlKunder(ele) {
    all.removeClass("active").addClass("passiv");
    all.eq(ele).removeClass("passiv").addClass("active");
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your anchor tags have an href of `#`, therefore when they are clicked, the page's hash is updated to `#` resulting in a scroll to top. Prevent the default action to make it stop.

```
$('#prev').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a reference to the `event` in the `callback function` of the `click`. We reference it here with the variable `e`. Then use `e.preventDefault()`; to stop the default page jump.

```
$('#prev').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // add this
    ctrlKunder( i = !i ? all.length - 1 : --i );
});
$('#next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // add this
    ctrlKunder( i = ++i % all.length );
}).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or `return false;` here:

```
$('#prev').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // return false;
   ctrlKunder( i = !i ? all.length - 1 : --i );
});
$('#next').click(function() {
   e.preventDefault(); // return false;
   ctrlKunder( i = ++i % all.length );
}).click();
```

You can use `return false;` too. `return false;` will also stop the event bubbling.

---

### From the Docs:

#### Description:

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.

Change the `href` in the next/prev links to `javascript:;` OR

Change click events to:

```
$('#prev').click(function(e) {
    ctrlKunder( i = !i ? all.length - 1 : --i );
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#next').click(function(e) {
    ctrlKunder( i = ++i % all.length );
    e.preventDefault();
}).click();
```